# Android Google FlexboxLayout : get lines or columns number

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-flexboxlayout

I am using the [Google's FlexboxLayout Android library](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

I'm searching how to get the number of rows (when the `flexDirection` property is set to `row` or `row_reverse`) or columns (when the `flexDirection` property is set to `column` or `column_reverse`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `FlexboxLayout.getFlexLines()` returns a list of instances of `com.google.android.flexbox.FlexLine`, each holds properties related to a a line on the main axis of the `FlexBoxLayout`.
I just have to retrieve the size of the list to get the number of lines on the main axis.

Note that `FlexboxLayout.getFlexLines()` returns the **number of actual lines -1**.

Comment: Good if you found the solution, but may you please add some description about the solution, to help stack overflow community.

Comment: After flex view has rendered

Comment: @Yairopro, "FlexboxLayout.getFlexLines()" always returns number of actual lines-1, as a result we are getting 0 although there is 1 flex line present. can you please suggest on the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @SubhalaxmiNayak. What do you mean by suggesting on the same ?

Comment: @Yairopro  same thing I have notice so this is probably not the right answer

Comment: I corrected the answer to tell people that the function returns the number of lines -1.

Comment: @Yairopro, FlexboxLayout.getFlexLines() should return always the correct value. So how to get the correct one. Please read my above comment for details.